# Rows Duplicates MUI DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, material-ui

I have a Data Grid component of the MUI and I am fetching data using axios, of course the objective is to show the data fetched in the Data Grid component, when I looked in the console it returns me correct, but in the page it returns me only one result o duplicating.

I believe there is a problem with the front-end but I am not able to identify it.

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejyi2.png)

```
//Code

export default function ListGrid() {

  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<IDados[]>([]);  

  interface IDados {
    empresa: number,
    nome: string,
    matricula: number,
    ano: number,
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoad(true);

    if (load === true) {

      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/questionarios/all", {
          headers: {
            ...getTokenAuth()
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setUsers(res.data);
          // console.log(res.data);
        })

    }

  }, [load]);  

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'empresa',
      headerName: 'Empresa',
      width: 120,
      headerAlign: 'center',
      align: 'center',
    },

    {
      field: 'nome',
      headerName: 'Nome',
      width: 250,
      headerAlign: 'center',
      align: 'center',
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        return params.getValue(params.id, "colaborador").nome;
      }
    },

    {
      field: 'matricula',
      headerName: 'Matrícula',
      width: 150,
      headerAlign: 'center',
      align: 'center',
    },

    {
      field: 'ano',
      headerName: 'Ano',
      width: 150,
      headerAlign: 'center',
      align: 'center',
    },

    
  ];

  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={users}
        columns={columns}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
        localeText={ptBR.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
        pageSize={pageSize}
        onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
        pagination
        initialState={{
          filter: {
            filterModel: {
              items: [],
              quickFilterLogicOperator: GridLinkOperator.Or,
            },
          },
        }}
        components={{ Toolbar: barraPesquisa }}
        getRowId={(row: any) => row.name + row.matricula}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your warning message seems to indicate some keys are NaN. Maybe you have a problem with

```
getRowId={(row: any) => row.name + row.matricula}
```

which return NaN for some rows